# Observe Collection (Bind To Datagid) - Error Threading

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, binding, collections

I have the following setup:

```
public class Monitor
{
    public ObservableCollection<People> listOfPeople = new ObservableCollection<People>();


    public dosomework() {
        Thread t = new ThreadStart(longwork);
        t.Start();
    }

   public longwork() {
        listOfPeople.Add(new People());
        Thread.Sleep(10000);

   }

}

public class People : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    int _age;
    public int Age
    {
        get { return _age; }
        set
        {
            _age = value;
            Notify("Age");
        }
    }
}

public class UI : Window
{
    Monitor md = new Monitor();
}
```

I want to bind a datagrid to the observable collection (datagrid.ItemSource = md.listOfPeople), however, I am getting a threading error. ALso, if I don't do the long work on a new thread, then the UI only updates after the longwork function finishes. I thought that binding would avoid this issue.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: This question can be helpfull: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7994638/update-ui-async/7995272#7995272

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned by others, if you do any work on the thread other than the UI, you must dispatch to the UI thread to actually update any element that is bound to a UI element.

In your example, that would be fairly easy. Just pass the `Dispatcher` ([msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatcher.aspx)) of your window to your `Monitor` and use that to dispatch accordingly:

```
...
Monitor md = new Monitor(this.Dispatcher);
...
public Monitor(Dispatcher dispatcher)
{
     _dispatcher = dispatcher;
}
...
public longwork() {
    _dispatcher.BeginInvoke((Action)(()=>listOfPeople.Add(new People()));
    Thread.Sleep(10000);

}
```

You could call `Dispatcher.Invoke` instead of `Dispatcher.BeginInvoke`, but if you don't care about the outcome and you want to move on fast, `BeginInvoke` is your friend.

Answer (score 1):

Binding is just "other code listening for changes", so threading is still an issue.

The usual fix is to do the Add to the list on the UI thread, as that is where the Grid will be listening from, but this will give poor performance if run for single elements.

Best to batch up the additions into a temp list running on the background thread and call AddRange at intervals (every 100 items?) to move that batch onto the UI collection to give better response and regular DataGrid updating.

Answer (score 0):

The databound datagrid is subscribed to the CollectionChanged event.  In my experience, the CollectionChanged event is raised on whatever thread caused the collection to change.  In this case, it is not the UI thread.  Since UI elements can only be modified from the UI thread, and the event is raised and handled on a non-UI thread, you will get your "Threading Error".

As stated above, a simple solution is to only modify the ObservableCollection from the UI thread.

If you are using WPF or Silverlight, all FrameworkElements have a Dispatcher property that you can use to perform work on the UI thread.  See also: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatcherobject.aspx