# Changing the Background color of a button

Tags: c#

I have written this code:

```
public partial class MainWindow : MetroWindow
{
    private static byte[] _buffer = new byte[1024];
    private static List<Socket> _clientSockets = new List<Socket>();
    private static Socket _serverSocket = new Socket
        (AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);

    private void MetroWindow_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        SetupServer();
    }

    public void changeColorButton()
    {
        var custom = new BrushConverter();
        testButton.Background = (Brush)custom.ConvertFrom("#FF00D400");
    }

    private static void SetupServer()
    {
        _serverSocket.Bind(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 100));
        MessageBox.Show("Server ONLINE");
        _serverSocket.Listen(5);
        _serverSocket.BeginAccept(new AsyncCallback(AcceptCallBack), null);
    }

    private static void AcceptCallBack(IAsyncResult AR)
    {
        Socket socket = _serverSocket.EndAccept(AR);
        _clientSockets.Add(socket);

        -----<triggers the changeColorButton() here>---

        s.Add(socket);
        socket.BeginReceive(_buffer, 0, _buffer.Length, SocketFlags.None, new AsyncCallback(ReceiveCallBack), socket);
        _serverSocket.BeginAccept(new AsyncCallback(AcceptCallBack), null);
    }

}
```

It accepts clients that will try to connect into the server. I also have a button for testing. I am trying to change the colour of the button when a client tries to connect to the server.

I tried to call changeColorButton() using this code:

```
    MainWindow m = new MainWindow();
    m.changeColorButton;
```

but it seems that I got an error on this one. Any suggestions on how I can change the colour of the button on whenever there is a client that will try to connect to the server? thank you. :)

Comment: I tried to call `changeColorButton()`. Yes that's how you need to. `m.changeColorButton()` and not `m.changeColorButton;`

Comment: What's the error? Threading, maybe? WPF is touchy about who's allowed to update the user interface when. [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7996225/3438854) is VB.NET, but may point in the right direction.

Comment: sorry, i forgot to put a parenthesis on changeColorButton; when i try to run my program server there is no error that has been appeared but when a client try to connect the program server will get error. It says "the calling thread must be STA, because many UI components requires this". The error appear on this code MainWindow m = new MainWindow();

Answer (score 0):

try `ConvertFromString` instead of `ConvertFrom`